# Pickling unpicklable objects

Tags: python, pygame, pickle, save, savestate

I am making a drawing program with pygame in which I want to give the user an option of saving the exact state of the program and then reloading it at a later time. 
At this point I save a copy of my globals dict and then iterate through, pickling every object. There are some objects in pygame that cannot be pickled, but can be converted into strings and pickled that way. My code is set up to do this, but some of these unpicklable objects are being reached by reference. In other words, they aren't in the global dictionary, but they are referenced by objects in the global dictionary. I want to pickle them in this recursion, but I don't know how to tell pickle to return the object it had trouble with, change it, then try to pickle it again. My code is really very kludge, if there's a different, superior way to do what I'm trying to do, let me know.

```
surfaceStringHeader = 'PYGAME.SURFACE_CONVERTED:'
imageToStringFormat = 'RGBA'
def save_project(filename=None):
    assert filename != None, "Please specify path of project file"
    pickler = pickle.Pickler(file(filename,'w'))
    for key, value in globals().copy().iteritems():
        #There's a bit of a kludge statement here since I don't know how to 
        #access module type object directly
        if type(value) not in [type(sys),type(None)]   and \
        key not in ['__name__','value','key']          and \
        (key,value) not in pygame.__dict__.iteritems() and \
        (key,value) not in sys.__dict__.iteritems()    and \
        (key,value) not in pickle.__dict__.iteritems(): 
        #Perhaps I should add something to the above to reduce redundancy of
        #saving the program defaults?
            #Refromat unusable objects:
            if type(value)==pygame.Surface:
                valueString = pygame.image.tostring(value,imageToStringFormat)
                widthString = str(value.get_size()[0]).zfill(5)
                heightString = str(value.get_size()[1]).zfill(5)
                formattedValue = surfaceStringHeader+widthString+heightString+valueString
            else:
                formattedValue = value

            try:
                pickler.dump((key,formattedValue))
            except Exception as e:
                print key+':' + str(e)

def open_project(filename=None):
    assert filename != None, "Please specify path to project file"
    unpickler = pickle.Unpickler(file(filename,'r'))
    haventReachedEOF = False
    while haventReachedEOF:
        try:
            key,value = unpickler.load()
            #Rework the unpicklable objects stored 
            if type(value) == str and value[0:25]==surfaceStringHeader:
                value = pygame.image.frombuffer(value[36:],(int(value[26:31]),int(value[31:36])),imageToStringFormat)
            sys.modules['__main__'].__setattr__(key,value)
        except EOFError:
            haventReachedEOF = True
```

Comment: This seems very buggy. Be explicit about the values you want to save and you'll spare yourself from a lot of hassle.

Comment: Seconded. I can say from experience that precisely defining the state of the program is some work up front, but encourages better design and forces you to think your state through (which will come in handy when debugging).

Comment: The hard part of your problem is that the state of your program includes running a live interpreter for the user, which can be used to modify the state of the drawing. You didn't mention that anywhere in the original question.

Answer (score 5):

In short: Don't do this.

Pickling everything in your application is messy and likely to cause problems. Take the data you need from your program and store it in an appropriate data format manually, then load it by creating the things you need back from that data.

Comment: The program operates alongside a live interpreter allowing users to rewrite or add functions and datastructures. I'd like to have these preserved and redefined when their project is loaded, so I can't restrict the pickling to predefined variables. Is there no way to save the state of a python program?

Comment: @hedgehogrider: There is no way to save the complete state of a Python program under all circumstances. Both `ipython` and `scipy` have limited implementations of this idea that go beyond `pickle` (for that matter, `multiprocessing` extends `pickle` beyond the stock), so you may want to look to them for ideas. But do you need the user to be able to, e.g., monkeypatch part of your framework and have that restorable?

Comment: What you are suggesting is not a simple task. Whether it is possible or not is beyond my knowledge, but you might want to ask yourself it is is really needed to have so much scope.

Answer (score 4):

You want to save the state of your entire program so that it can be reloaded at a later time. This is a perfect use case for Pickle, I don't see a problem with the use case at all. However your approach to pickling the globals() namespace and filtering out sys, pygame and pickle is wonky. The usual pattern is to have one session object which you pickle.

Also I think there might be some confusion with how to pickle:

1. When you pickle an object, all of the objects referenced by its
   member variables will be pickled/unpickled automatically, which is
   good
2. If pickle cannot serialize an object, you should tell pickle
   how to save and restore that object by writing custom [**getstate**
   and **setstate**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) methods for any objects that don't pickle, so
   one or two of your classes that are nested inside your master
   session object will have custom **get/setstate** functions to do
   things like reopen devices like filehandles that will obviously be
   different between sessions
3. If you need to do a binary serialization
   you don't need to cast the object into a string, just use the binary
   serialization protocol in that object's **get/setstate** method,
   ([ie use Protocol 1](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format))

In the end your code should look more like this:

```
session = None
import pickle
def startsession():
    globals session
    session = pickle.Unpickler(sessionfilehandle('r')).load()
    if session is None: session = Session() 

def savesession(filename=None):
    globals session
    pickle.Pickler.dump(session,sessionfilehandle('w'))

class Session(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.someobject=NewObject1()
        #.... plus whole object tree representing the whole game
        self.somedevicehandlethatcannotbepickled=GetDeviceHandle1()  #for example
    def __getstate__(self):
        odict = self.__dict__.copy()
        del odict['somedevicehandlethatcannotbepickled'] #don't pickle this
        return odict
    def __setstate__(self, dict):
        self.__dict__.update(dict)
        self.somedevicehandlethatcannotbepickled=GetDeviceHandle1()
```

Comment: BTW, I don't see an issue with saving state of a liveinterpreter. It's just another object which contains a member dictionary which is the user's namespace. Dictionaries pickle right off the bat, nothing special there. You are probably already executing this custom user code using the exec keyword with the format that specifies which namespace to run against.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer Riaz! But, question: How to I inject another method into an existing class that I did not create? Should I subclass it, then set the original to the subclass or is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Pickling aside then. To inject another method into an existing class, as long as they are extensible like normal python classes then there should be no problem. For classes like dict that are not extensible subclassing: class MyDict(dict): pass  will do the trick. Though more could be said here. It might be better to create a separate question.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up! I'll look into it separately!

Comment: In theory this works, but in practice it's not practical… or at least is a hell of a lot of painstaking work (i.e. it could take months to years).  Have you tried to do what you are suggesting (specifically, #2 and your code)?  The OP is dealing with a game in the interpreter… so *any* object could be in the session.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments, it sounds like the hard part of what you're trying to do is to give the user a live interpreter, and save the state of *that*.

So, what about running that live interpreter as a subprocess? Any information from your object model that you want to expose to scripting, you do so explicitly (whether by `multiprocessing` shared memory, or some kind of message-passing API).

Then, you don't need to save the complete state of your own interpreter, which is either very hard or impossible; you save your data model in the normal way, and then you can freeze the sub-interpreter from the outside rather than the inside.

This is obviously a lot more complicated than what you're trying to do, but I don't think that anything simple is actually going to work. For example, if the user has a live interpreter with your code, they can monkeypatch anything—even the pickling code—and then what happens? You need to define some limitations on exactly what can be saved and restored—and, if those limitations are broad enough, I think you have to do it from outside.

Meanwhile, as mentioned in a comment, both `scipy` (or some associated project that comes with Enthought) and `ipython` have save-and-restore functionality for limited use cases, which at least gives you some code to study, but their use cases may not be the same as yours.

Answer (score 2):

If you know all the unpickleable object types then the code in the answer to this question might be helpful " [Recursively dir() a python object to find values of a certain type or with a certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611337/recursively-dir-a-python-object-to-find-values-of-a-certain-type-or-with-a-cer) " -- I wrote it in response to a similar situation where I knew all the unpickleable object types but I couldn't know where they were within a data structure.  You could use this code to find them, replace them with something else then on unpickling use similar code to put them back.

Answer (score 2):

To do this, I use [dill](http://pythonhosted.org/dill), which can serialize almost anything in python. Dill also has [some good tools](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/blob/master/dill/detect.py) for helping you understand what is causing your pickling to fail when your code fails. Also, [objgraph](http://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/) is a pretty handy compliment to the test suite too.

```
>>> import dill
>>> # blah blah blah... your session code here
>>> dill.dump_session('pygame.pkl')
>>>
>>> # and if you get a pickling error, use dill's tools to discover a workaround
>>> dill.detect.badobjects(your_bad_object, depth=1)
>>>
>>> # visualize the references in your bad objects
>>> objgraph.show_refs(your_bad_object, filename='pygame_bad_object.png')
```

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048061/how-to-pickle-a-python-function-with-its-dependencies/19414069#19414069