# Cannot pickle connection object

Tags: python, sql-server, database, connection, pickle

I am using following code to connect to the SQL Server and return the connection in order to be able to use in other function. However, I am getting an error of `can't pickle pyodbc.Connection objects`

The code is:

```
def connect_to_the_DB(**kwargs):
    #Connection to SQL Server
    conn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}',
                          server='test.co.uk',
                          database='testdb',
                          uid='crm',
                          pwd='test123')
    print("Connection established")
    logging.info("Connection established")
    return conn
```

Any tips, how I can solve it?

Comment: How do you call the `connect_to_the_DB` function?

Comment: I am using Apache Airflow. So, I am assigning functions to the tasks.@CDJB

Comment: This is like my favorite post title on SO

Answer (score 2):

Some objects are not picklable (see [Pickling unpicklable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691185/pickling-unpicklable-objects)). I've had the same issue with Redis connections which seem similar to this, though I'm not sure.

The general advice is to extract the data you need and only pickle that, rather than the connection itself.